# angular html search popover doesnt recognize angular variables

Tags: angularjs, compilation

we are trying to put  a popover search on each column in our ng table but when the popover is shown, it doesnt recognize any scope variable or at least it's not found any since none of the {{item}} resolved to value.. but the ng-click is recognized and triggered. Please help. Im trying a solution that would work with IE 8 too and angular strap doesnt. plunk: [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3pnP0qK9bzqf1JnA2L6m?p=preview)

```
<a class="input-group-addon sml-input-text clickable filterAnchor" style="padding: 4px 5px;" toggle="popover" role="button" class="pop-function" colname="{{column.attributeValue}}">
    <label class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter clickable" aria-hidden="true"></label>
</a>
```

popover html:

```
<div id="advancedFilter" class="popover">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-content no-margin no-padding">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-bottom: 0px;width: 450px;">
                <div class="panel-heading">Filter</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <span>Show rows where {{colName}}</span>
                    <form action="">
                        <div class="row show-grid" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select ng-model="search.firstSearchKey">
                                <option ng-repeat="item in allSearchOptions" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
                            </select>                       
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 no-margin" style="padding-left:0px">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control sml-input-text" placeholder="Enter value"  style="width:200px"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Directive

```
.directive('toggle', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict : 'A',
                controller: function($scope, $element){
                    $scope.colName='abc';
                    $scope.hidePopover=function(){
                        $($element).popover('toggle');
                    }
                    $scope.search=function(){
                        $($element).popover('toggle');
                    }
                    $scope.allSearchOptions = ['one','two'];
                },scope: {},
                link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    if (attrs.toggle == "popover") {
                        scope.option={
                                placement: 'bottom',
                                container: 'body',
                                html: true,
                                content: function () {
                                    return $compile(angular.element($('#advancedFilter').html()))(scope);
                                }
                            }
                        $(element).popover(scope.option);
                    }
                }
            };
        })
```

Comment: Keep popover html in on file and call through directive "template" and while calling pass you object from html directive tag

Comment: please explain a little more of the solution. i understand that if html is rendered on screen, it's somehow bound to rootscope and the $compile is not helping in binding variable but i dont know how to load this html conditionally

Comment: you can use ng-if or ng-show for more details on directives check below link
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

Comment: im injecting the html content of the popover inside the popover and not the element which is invoked... if i use the template attribute, it will replace the component which is clicked on. You can check my plunk above

Comment: i tried to put the html content in template and use: content: function () {
 return  $compile($templateCache.get('advancedSearch.html'))(scope); } but this time, it shows {{colName}} on screen instead of blank like before... also not what i wanted